# How do I convert md files to HTML and render them in Django

Tags: python, html, django, markdown

I have some md files in an 'entries' folder in my django app folder and i wanna get them, covert them to HTML then render them.
This is my util.py

```
def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None


def convert_md(filename):
    """
    Converts given md file to html
    """
    #file= f"{filename}.md"

    file= default_storage.open(f"{filename}.md")
    md= file.read()
    html= md.markdown(md)
    return html
```

This is my views.py

```
def wiki(request, topic):
    if util.get_entry(topic) != None:
        html= util.convert_md(topic)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/pages.html", {
            "title": topic, "body": html 
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/pages.html", {
            "title": "ERROR", "body": "THIS PAGE IS NOT AVALIABLE."
        })
```

I also have...

```
path("wiki/<str:topic>", views.wiki)
```

in my urls.py but I'm still getting a **FileNotFoundError at /wiki/Python** error
**Note:** I have pip installed markdown

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same `FileNotFound` exception, but i have found the answer finally.

Md files are located in `entries` folder, so you have to specify that in `convert_md` function in utils.py just like in `get_entry` function.

```py
file = default_storage.open(f"entries/{filename}.md", "r")
```

I hope this will fix your issue as it did mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

`pip install markdown` on your console/terminal.

Then try the following:

```
import markdown
f = open("MDFile.md","r")
f = f.read()
html = markdown.markdown(f)
```

where MDFile.md are your markdown files. `html` will have the HTML version of your markdown file.

Comment: Note: if you want to process multiple md files at once, just use a loop. Hope this helps!